# Zend Framework - isValid return false, but getMessages() is empty

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm doing something like this in controller:

```
$form->getElement('e_mail')->addError('Invalid');

var_dump($form->getMessages()); // print my error correctly

$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()); // return false

var_dump($form->getMessages()); // print empty array
```

Why after **isValid**() array is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your controller Action

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

     if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){

        $form->getValues();

        $form->getElement('e_mail')->addError('Invalid');


       }
        var_dump($form->getMessages());
    }
```